# BAPI Function Rollback on asp.net web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, abap, bapi, sap-erp

I Have a C# web application that call multiple BAPI and stored procedure at one of the function in ASP.net Website. i need to rollback all the bapi executed on the function that called on the web if one of the method inside the function is failed.

in SQL I call

```
SqlTransaction transaction = connectionsql.BeginTransaction();
...
transaction.Rollback();
```

on the c# code if one of the method failed. (this can be done for sql rollback)

but for the SAP BAPI , even if i call BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK on C# catch statement , the changes is still there. (rollback not success)

FYI , in my BAPI Function i use CSAP_MAT_BOM_MAINTAIN to update the BOM information.

is there any way to do rollback like sql transaction on my C# code for SAP BAPI Function and rollback all the BAPI run on C# if the web catch an exception ?

Comment: The post is more about SAP and BAPI. As far as I know if there is something failed in halfway, BAPI will do rollback which means handled by SAP itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. Ideally, you should be able to do the following from your ASP.net code:

1. Call BAPI 1.
2. Call BAPI 2.
3. etc.
4. If success, call `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT`, if error, call `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK`.

Unfortunately, if the BAPIs contain a `COMMIT` themselves (and many older ones and non-BAPI function modules do), your `ROLLBACK` will be too late - the data will already have been committed.

In your case, function module `CSAP_MAT_BOM_MAINTAIN` contains a `FL_COMMIT_AND_WAIT` parameter but this only affects whether the `COMMIT` waits (a commit still occurs either way). There may be a workaround, however: in subroutine `CSAP_MAIN_INIT` (include `LCSAPF01`) in my system, there is this line of code:

```
import flg_no_commit_work  from memory id 'CS_CSAP'.
```

This flag (`flg_no_commit_work`) is later passed into a call to function module `CS_DI_BOM_VB` (called from `CSAP_MAT_BOM_MAINTAIN`) and if it's set, no `COMMIT` is done. Perhaps try setting that flag via an `EXPORT TO MEMORY` and see if that helps. Of course, this is undocumented and unsupported by SAP but it may well work...

Comment: Thank you very much. now i know why exactly my BAPI failed to rollback. you were correct the CSAP_MAT_BOM_MAINTAIN contains FL_COMMIT_AND_WAIT param which later will be process and commit the changes if the flag (flg_no_commit_work) is not set. the following code solve the problem. ( source from : https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/182580 ) 

data: flg_no_commit_work type c.
flg_no_commit_work = 'X'.
   export flg_no_commit_work  to memory id 'CS_CSAP'.

Comment: By Using SE37 testing it in sequence the Commit and rollback was working. but on web even i share multiple bapi at the same connection , the commit fail . i am using SAP connector at the moment is there any sample that i can use to use this rollback on my c# asp.net web application ?

Comment: So the call to `CSAP_MAT_BOM_MAINTAIN` was successful (ie it returns values indicating that the BOM was updated) but the data isn't being committed? It may be worthwhile debugging the SAP side of the call to see if you can figure out why it's not working.

Comment: on webservice if i put repository.CreateFunction("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");   function.invoke(destination); at the end of the webservice code after completing invoke the first BAPI, the data is saved. however if i call it seperately ,its not saved and data is locked. i put  RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(destination); at the first bapi and another seperate bapi is called end with RfcSessionManager.EndContext(destination); (after commit called).i also put IRfcFunction , RfcDestination , and RfcRepository as static variable so it will never reset or changed. is there anything that i missed ?

Answer (score 2):

first you have to check if the BAPIs contain a `COMMIT WORK` statement. Of course this will disturb your transaction handling.

Next you have to take care of correct session handling. You have put the following function calls around your BAPI calls.

```
RfcSessionManager.BeginContext()
```

and

```
RfcSessionManager.EndContext()
```

Without this context bracket every BAPI call will be executed in a different context.